# Can't set cookie using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

How can I set a cookie using Chrome Extension? I'm working on a login to my web page through Chrome Extension. I have to set `sessionid` but it does not work.

The alert in `success` function is visible but then, it doesn't log in nor redirects page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login-button-id').click(function () {

        var login = $('#input-email-id').val();
        var password = $('#input-password-id').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/authenticate',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'login': login,
                'password': password
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $.cookie('sessionid',data.sessionid);
                chrome.cookies.set({"sessionid":data.sessionid});
                alert("You are logged in");
                window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin";
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("JQuery failed: " + textStatus + " with error thrown: " + errorThrown);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        })
    });
    $('#logout-button-id').click(function () {

    })
});
```

**MANIFEST**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "xyz",
  "description": "This is a plugin collaborating with xyz.com",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "spy-icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "cookies",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

I suppose it's because Chrome Extension is a sandbox so it has it's own cookies but can't figure out what to do, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suppose it's because Chrome Extension is a sandbox so it has it's own cookies

Indeed, since you're trying to use this from an extension's own page, that binds the cookie you're trying to set via `$.cookie` to extension's own origin (`chrome-extension://somelongextensionidhere/`). So this doesn't work.

As for [`chrome.cookies.set`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-set), you need to read documentation on how you use it!

Proper invocation should be something like this:

```
chrome.cookies.set({
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
  name: "sessionid",
  value: data.sessionid
});
```

Comment: Thanks Xan. The problem is that console says:  >>> login.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined <<< But in manifest, there is "cookies" in permissions... This is a login.js script, not popup.js

Comment: I assume `login.js` is a content script. In that case, you can't use `chrome.cookies` from it, and must delegate it to a background script.

Comment: Yes, I've just defined it in manifest: "background": { "scripts": ["login.js"]} and it works! Thanx Xan!